# How can Mentally ill people be judged by their actions?

Tags: jannah, judgements

My question is pretty clear, how can mentally ill people be judged by their actions if they are not aware of they are doing? why are them even put on this earth?

Comment: You seem adamant about them being judge, do you have any reference of such or is this a mere guess?

Comment: What I mean is : If a mentally ill person dies, it goes to Jannah or not? and based on what actions does it get judged?

Comment: Imo, you should be asking "will they be judge" not "how can they be judge".

Answer (score 1):

These are two questions ...

As for your 1st question:
"how can mentally ill people be judged by their actions if they are not aware of they are doing?"

This should be answered by **no** they wont or shouldn't be judged!

> Narrated Ali ibn AbuTalib:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said: There are three (persons) whose actions are not
>   recorded: a sleeper till he awakes, a boy till he reaches puberty, and
>   a lunatic till he comes to reason.
>
> Abu Dawud said: Ibn Juraij has transmitted it from Al-Qasim b. Yazid
>   on the authority of 'Ali from the Prophet (ﷺ). This version adds: "and
>   an old man who is feeble-minded."   [Sunan abu Dawod]
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، حَدَّثَنَا وُهَيْبٌ، عَنْ
>   خَالِدٍ، عَنْ أَبِي الضُّحَى، عَنْ عَلِيٍّ، عَلَيْهِ السَّلاَمُ عَنِ
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏"‏ رُفِعَ الْقَلَمُ عَنْ
>   ثَلاَثَةٍ عَنِ النَّائِمِ حَتَّى يَسْتَيْقِظَ وَعَنِ الصَّبِيِّ حَتَّى
>   يَحْتَلِمَ وَعَنِ الْمَجْنُونِ حَتَّى يَعْقِلَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو
>   دَاوُدَ رَوَاهُ ابْنُ جُرَيْجٍ عَنِ الْقَاسِمِ بْنِ يَزِيدَ عَنْ
>   عَلِيٍّ رضى الله عنه عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم زَادَ فِيهِ
>   ‏"‏ وَالْخَرِفِ ‏"

This Hadith was also narrated by A'isha in Sunan ibn-Majah and you can find Versions of it in Sunan An-Nisa'i and Jami' at-Tirmidhi.

Here's a clearer Version:

> Narrated Ali ibn AbuTalib: Ibn Abbas said: A lunatic woman who had
>   committed adultery was brought to Umar. He consulted the people and
>   ordered that she should be stoned.
>
> Ali ibn AbuTalib passed by and said: What is the matter with this
>   (woman)? They said: This is a lunatic woman belonging to a certain
>   family. She has committed adultery. Umar has given orders that she
>   should be stoned.
>
> He said: Take her back. He then came to him and said: Commander of the
>   Faithful, do you not know that there are three people whose actions
>   are not recorded: a lunatic till he is restored to reason, a sleeper
>   till he awakes, and a boy till he reaches puberty?
>
> He said: Yes. He then asked: Why is it that this woman is being
>   stoned?
>
> He said: There is nothing. He then said: Let her go. He (Umar) let her
>   go and began to utter: Allah is most great.
>
> [Sunan abi Dawod]
>
> حَدَّثَنَا عُثْمَانُ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا جَرِيرٌ، عَنِ
>   الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ أَبِي ظَبْيَانَ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ أُتِيَ
>   عُمَرُ بِمَجْنُونَةٍ قَدْ زَنَتْ فَاسْتَشَارَ فِيهَا أُنَاسًا فَأَمَرَ
>   بِهَا عُمَرُ أَنْ تُرْجَمَ فَمُرَّ بِهَا عَلَى عَلِيِّ بْنِ أَبِي
>   طَالِبٍ رِضْوَانُ اللَّهِ عَلَيْهِ فَقَالَ مَا شَأْنُ هَذِهِ قَالُوا
>   مَجْنُونَةُ بَنِي فُلاَنٍ زَنَتْ فَأَمَرَ بِهَا عُمَرُ أَنْ تُرْجَمَ
>   ‏.‏ قَالَ فَقَالَ ارْجِعُوا بِهَا ثُمَّ أَتَاهُ فَقَالَ يَا أَمِيرَ
>   الْمُؤْمِنِينَ أَمَا عَلِمْتَ أَنَّ الْقَلَمَ قَدْ رُفِعَ عَنْ
>   ثَلاَثَةٍ عَنِ الْمَجْنُونِ حَتَّى يَبْرَأَ وَعَنِ النَّائِمِ حَتَّى
>   يَسْتَيْقِظَ وَعَنِ الصَّبِيِّ حَتَّى يَعْقِلَ قَالَ بَلَى ‏.‏ قَالَ
>   فَمَا بَالُ هَذِهِ تُرْجَمُ قَالَ لاَ شَىْءَ ‏.‏ قَالَ فَأَرْسِلْهَا
>   ‏.‏ قَالَ فَأَرْسَلَهَا ‏.‏ قَالَ فَجَعَلَ يُكَبِّرُ ‏.‏

Some other evidence showing this:

> Yahya related to me from Malik from Yahya ibn Said that Marwan ibn
>   al-Hakam wrote to Muawiya ibn Abi Sufyan that a madman was brought to
>   him who had killed a man. Muawiya wrote to him, "Tie him up and do not
>   inflict any retaliation on him. There is no retaliation against a
>   madman."
>
> Malik said about an adult and a child when they murder a man together,
>   "The adult is killed and the child pays half the full blood-money."
>
> Malik said, "It is like that with a freeman and a slave when they
>   murder a slave. The slave is killed and the freeman pays half of his
>   value."
>
> [Muwatta' al Imam Malik]
>
> وَحَدَّثَنِي عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ سَعِيدٍ، أَنَّ مَرْوَانَ
>   بْنَ الْحَكَمِ، كَتَبَ إِلَى مُعَاوِيَةَ بْنِ أَبِي سُفْيَانَ أَنَّهُ
>   أُتِيَ بِمَجْنُونٍ قَتَلَ رَجُلاً ‏.‏ فَكَتَبَ إِلَيْهِ مُعَاوِيَةُ
>   أَنِ اعْقِلْهُ وَلاَ تُقِدْ مِنْهُ فَإِنَّهُ لَيْسَ عَلَى مَجْنُونٍ
>   قَوَدٌ ‏.
>
> ‏ قَالَ مَالِكٌ فِي الْكَبِيرِ وَالصَّغِيرِ إِذَا قَتَلاَ رَجُلاً
>   جَمِيعًا عَمْدًا أَنَّ عَلَى الْكَبِيرِ أَنْ يُقْتَلَ وَعَلَى
>   الصَّغِيرِ نِصْفُ الدِّيَةِ ‏.‏
>
> قَالَ مَالِكٌ وَكَذَلِكَ الْحُرُّ وَالْعَبْدُ يَقْتُلاَنِ الْعَبْدَ
>   فَيُقْتَلُ الْعَبْدُ وَيَكُونُ عَلَى الْحُرِّ نِصْفُ قِيمَتِهِ ‏.‏

About your 2nd Question i must say Allhu A'lam (Allah knows best).

But i want to add that not all of them were born sick!